# odbcDriverConnect issue trying to connect to an Access Database in R

Tags: r, database, rodbc

I am using R 32 bit and am having an issue trying to get the odbcDriverConnect function to work when trying to connect to an Access database.  I have successfully connect to the database using odbcConnect, but am also trying to learn how to use the odbcDriverConnect function.

My code is

```
scallopdata<-odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=S://adv/Scallop Central/2014 RSARR/2014 RSA Database_9_3_2014.mdb;
    Uid=admin;Pwd=")
```

When I run the code, I get an error message of 
ODBC Microsoft Access Driver Login Failed.  Could not find file  S://adv/Scallop Central/2014 RSARR/2014 RSA Database_9_3_2014.mdb.

I click the OK button which takes me to a Login box.  I select the Database... button.  This brings me to a Select Database box where I can select the same database that is specified in the Dbq section of code.  Once I select the correct database and click OK I am connected to the database.

I am hoping to use the odbcDriverConnect function so that I do not have to set up a new odbc DSN for each database I would like to access.  This may just be me not fully understanding the function.

If any one can provide so insight, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you considered using `odbcConnectAccess2007`?  This allows the database to be specified by file name.

Comment: I have the same issue using the odbcConnectAccess2007 function.